# Java reflection grabbing a non public field

Tags: java, reflection

I'm having trouble grabbing the fields in a class using reflection in Java:

```
public class CraftLib
{
    static List alloyRecipes = new ArrayList();
    public static HashSet damageOnCraft = new HashSet();
    public static HashMap damageContainer = new HashMap();

public static void addAlloyResult(ur output, Object[] input)
{
    alloyRecipes.add(Arrays.asList(new Object[] { input, output }));
}
//file continues
```

I try to grab the fields like this:

```
try {
    Field[] fields = Class.forName("class.path").getFields();
    for(Field f : fields) {
    System.out.println(f.getName());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Damn.");
}
System.out.println(fields.length);
```

For some reason it is only able to grab the `damageOnCraft` and `damageContainer` fields, but the one I really need, `alloyRecipes`, is not grabbed. I can not edit the first file, so what would be the best way to get and edit that field?

Answer (score 9):

[`getFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields()) won't give you private,  package-protected or protected fields if they are inaccessible.

> (getFields()) Returns an array containing Field objects reflecting all the **accessible public fields** of the class or interface represented by this Class object

And apparently your package-protected `alloyRecipes` are not accessible in your case.

You need [`getDeclaredFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields())

> (getDeclaredFields()) Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This **includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private fields**, but excludes inherited fields.

Answer (score 0):

Put your class in the same package as the other one then it will be able to read package protected fields.